# Put string like "name1.name2.name3" to JSON to access to key json

Tags: javascript

```
let myJson={
"name1": {
    "name2": {
        "name3": {
            "value": 5
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And I have this string:

```
let string="name1.name2.name3";
```

How to access to `myJson` using  this string? the result should be:

```
{ value:5 }
```

The right way is:

```
console.log(myJson.name1.name2.name3);
```

but I have a different scenario in which I must do so in the previous way (using the string).

Comment: Use a recursive function? A loop? There are a number of solutions to this.

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947813/2924577

Comment: @Nikhil can you give me a hand.. it is difficult..

Comment: @yavg - Give it a try. If you still don't get it, check out https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-41qvmp.

Comment: The solution in the duplicate is a good one. Have a look